# Retain root privileges during long processes

Tags: linux, bash, sudo

I have a bash script that makes a backup of my data files (~50GB). The script is basically something like this:

```
sudo tar /backup/mydata1 into old-backup-1.tar
sudo tar /backup/mydata2 into old-backup-2.tar
sudo rsync /mydata1 to /backup/mydata1
sudo rsync /mydata2 to /backup/mydata2
```

(I use sudo because some of the files are owned by root).

The problem is that after every command (because it takes a long time) I loose root privileges and if I'm not present at the computer then the su prompt gets timed out and the script ends in the middle of the job.

Is there a way to retain su privileges during the entire script? What is the best way to approach this situation? I prefer to run the script under my user.

Comment: Put your commands without sudo in a script and run your script with sudo.

Comment: I actually though about this and if there won't be any other elegant way to do it, this would be the method I'll choose, thanks

Comment: Configure `sudo` on your system to allow those commands to run without a password.

Comment: Alternative solution here that keeps resetting the timeout... https://serverfault.com/a/702019

Answer (score 1):

With a second shell:

```
sudo bash -c "command1; command2; command3; command4"
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and running the script with sudo?

Comment: With this variant you can save the sudo with every call of the script.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

exec sudo /bin/bash <<'EOF'
    echo I am $UID
    whoami
    #^the script
EOF
```

Alternatively, you could put something like:

```
if ! [ $(id -u)  -eq 0 ]; then
    exec sudo "$0" "$@"
fi
```

at the top.

Comment: The first approach has issues if "the script" itself tries to read from standard input, as `bash` is already reading the script itself from that file handle.